# What does "Skins" refer to?

Tags: skins

There was a UK youth drama *[Skins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skins_(UK_TV_series))* for 7 seasons and I am wondering the name has any specific meaning? Or is it just "The thin layer of tissue forming the natural outer covering of the body of a person or animal." according to Oxford Dictionary?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-British-TV-series-Skins-called-Skins

Comment: @BCdotWEB you may want to turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In British slang a "Skin" is the type of paper used to make roll your own cigarettes and joints.

Further down the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/skin) entry is this definition.

> 2.3informal A cigarette paper.
>   ‘I passed her a plastic bag with skins and hash inside’

The characters in the TV show Skins, that originated in the UK, and  was later adapted for the US are part of the youth culture that take drugs.

Answer (score -3):

I remember when this came out, the shows creator said it was slang for friends. NB I'm English and have never heard the term.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: touchy! idgaf man just trying to help - it was a US question and I'm british and student of media.